# vertically centered an image, based on the container height

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, responsive

edit:

http://eclassified.my/service/242/9d3a89c9-09ae-49a5-ae8c-a4c3070c7ead

How can I vertically centered an image, based on the container height.

Given the container height is fixed, and the image size is dynamic.

Currently only top part of the image is shown as we use overflow: hide;.

Thanks

Comment: The white part is actually part of the image, you want to hide it?

Comment: @randy Yes, it's part of the image, for some image that don't have any white part works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image `CSS` to `height: 100%`.

Please provide some codes, so that we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: I tried to put all the html and the css but the result ruin everything. not sure why. And if the i set the height 100%, the slider will follow the image size. I tried to adjust the image to follow the slider size.

Answer (score 0):

**Photoshop**

The easiest solution is obviously photoshop here; you can just resize the images.

---

**CSS**

You can use the CSS property `background-image` for this. The `img` tag is not made to hide parts of the image, only to resize.

To do this, you can use the following example:

```
background-position: 0px -60px;
```

That property is the key to create a background image that fits in your slideshow. However; you will need to manually change that for all images.

Example for you to use `background-position`:

```css
.slider-nav-crop4 {
  /*this is your image with ~60px white space above */
  background-image:url('http://eclassified.my/ec_admin/upload/service_upload/draft-guwz8z2ux1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0px -60px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="crop-image slider-nav-crop4" style="border-radius:8px;display:inline-block;width:400px;height:300px;">
  
</div>
```

---

**Positioning the image**

This is actually a hack that can be set per image, but it could be a little tricky.

You can position the images absolute, give them a negative `top` setting and make the images larger then the container, setting `overflow:hidden`.

*example*

```css
.item .crop-image {
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.crop-image img {
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner1" role="listbox" style="border-radius:8px;">

  <div class="item item1" style="border-radius:8px;">
    <div class="crop-image slider-nav-crop4" style="border-radius:8px;">
      <img src="http://eclassified.my/ec_admin/upload/service_upload/draft-bxkh1mt89q.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item item1 active left" style="border-radius:8px;">
    <div class="crop-image slider-nav-crop4" style="border-radius:8px;">
      <img src="http://eclassified.my/ec_admin/upload/service_upload/draft-guwz8z2ux1.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item item1 next left" style="border-radius:8px;">
    <div class="crop-image slider-nav-crop4" style="border-radius:8px;">
      <img src="http://eclassified.my/ec_admin/upload/service_upload/draft-83ytvl4obn.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
  </div>
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: So this image is actually from the database of the program. I think it will be impossible if we put the image source on the css as the background. I've tried it but can't

Comment: @RendyJuvi I've updated the answer with another option.

Comment: @RendyJuvi Sometimes you have to use what you get. If you can't change the images, can't change the CSS, then I can't make it any better then this. The only thing you can try, is % instead of `px`.

Comment: so sorry before, i just had a huge expectation on this, I just thought there are another way for it. I had to try it first.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your code is,

```
<div class="image">
    <img scr="Image_path" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image{
    position: relative;
}
.image img{
    margin: auto; //horizontally align center
    position: absolute; //vertically align center
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
container {
display: table;
vertical align: middle;
}
img {
display: table-cell;
vertical align: middle;
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
container {
position: relative;
}
image {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

**Method 3:**

```
container {
height: 300px;
line-height: 300px;
}
```

In css vertical alignment is a very discussed topic, this is 3 of many examples. Use the best for you.